# Where do I get the 'androidClientId' in Firebase console?

Tags: flutter, firebase

The FirebaseOptions class from the FlutterFire library takes an options 'androidClientId' parameter.

The docs are as follows...

```
  /// The Android client ID from the Firebase Console, for example
  /// "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com."
  ///
  /// This value is used by iOS only.
  final String? androidClientId;
```

Inside my Firebase console, I have no value specifically named 'androidClientId' and I have no value matching the format specified in the comment.

Where do I get this value from?

Answer (score 0):

This string only matters when initializing Firebase when running on an Android device.  If you aren't running on Android, you shouldn't need it at all.

If you are initializing on Android, that means you must have registered your Android app in the Firebase console.  The client ID for that app is found in the google-services.sjon you can download for your Android app from the console.  You can get the steps for all this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).  The `client_id` property will be visible in the downloaded JSON.

The reason why this value is not easily visible in the console is because most app initialize Firebase use the downloaded config file, which contains everything need to initialize Firebase automatically without having to copy values from anywhere.

Comment: I am not initializing using the google-services.json. I am running a multi-project system with automatically provisioned projects.

Comment: You can still download a google-sevices.json for any registered Android app or use the REST API to get the app's config.